# "NSArray is not convertible to NSData" error

Tags: ios, json, swift, socket.io

I am using socket.io with swift in iOS. I have to read a json.

My Json:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "username": "testuser1",
            "password": "testuser1",
            "phone": "+905557664823"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "username": "testuser2",
            "password": "testuser2",
            "phone": "+905555648584"
        }
    ]
}
```

My code:

```
    self.socket.on("contactList") {data, ack in
        let jsonResult: Dictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
        let results: NSArray = jsonResult["result"] as! NSArray
    }
```

But I am getting the following compiler error:

> 'NSArray' is not convertible to 'NSData'

How can I fix it?

Ps: the `data` variable contains the json.

Comment: What's the type of the `data`? NSArray?

Comment: Actually, don't know. I am using this library: https://github.com/nuclearace/Socket.IO-Client-Swift

Comment: It's NSArray. Maybe you should print it on console first.

Comment: It looks like this: http://prntscr.com/8cggml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
let resultData = (data.firstObject as! String).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
let jsonResult: Dictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(resultData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
let results: NSArray = jsonResult["result"] as! NSArray
```

Comment: Change `data` to `resultData`

Comment: Could you explain the first line? What is doing it?

Comment: The `data.firstObject` is a JSON string like this:`"{"result":[{"id":1,"username":"testuser1","password":"testuser1","phone":"+905557664823"}]}"`. For some reason, that library returns data to you as NSArray like `["{result:xxxx}"]`, so you have to get the first object and convert into NSData, then you can call `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData`